# create RestSharp equivalent for Curl command

Tags: c#, curl, restsharp

Here is the curl.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -vX POST -d "[\"Channel1.Device1.tag1\"]" host_name/read
```

I need to convert it into restSharp code,

At the moment, I am doing,

```
var client = new RestClient("host_name/read");

var request = new RestRequest( Method.POST);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

I don't know how to fix this `-d` param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the question. Please see the below link for the answer it works like a charm.

http://www.hackered.co.uk/articles/sending-json-strings-with-restsharp